# jquery show hidden div

Tags: jquery

Firstly, I'm sort of embarrassed asking about this, so many people have already asked this question but even after having gone through so many posts, I'm unable to achieve what I want.
Basically, a div, initially hidden, has to be displayed on a button click.

I tried hiding the div using `display:none` and `hide()` and then displaying it using `show()`, `toggle()`, and `css("display","block")`. Using all sorts of combinations of the above, I was still unable to get the result.

Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jQuery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#one').hide();
        $('#Button1').click(function () {
            $('#one').toggle(500);
        });         
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="one" style="height: 20px;width:200px; background-color: Red; ">       
</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

On button click, the div is shown for a brief second before it disappears again.

The same thing happens if I use `show()` instead of `toggle()` in the above code.

Again the same thing if I set `style="display:none"` to the div instead of using `hide()` and then use `show()` or `toggle()`.

I also tried using `$('#one').css("display","block");` but again, the same result.

Can anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong. Just started learning jQuery and it is really frustrating when something apparently so simple will not work.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using button with type `button`  as `asp:Button` rendered in browser having `type="submit"` , so  use `return false;` as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#one').hide();
        $('#Button1').click(function () {
            $('#one').toggle(500);
            return false;
        });         
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting the form and the page is reloaded, the default type of the button element is *submit*, you can try using `preventDefault` method of the event object or set the type attribute of the button to `button`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#one').hide();
    $('#Button1').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#one').toggle(500);
    });         
});
```